# Jquery How to like switch to next tab in ASP MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I have a view like this

View Code:-

```
<div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:white" id="Tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-left">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-9 tabs-left" style="background-color:white">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <div class="panel-body fixed-panel">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        @Html.DropDownList("List", new SelectList(ViewBag.List, "ListID", "ListDescription"), "Select", new { id = "List1"})
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default pull-right nexttab">Continue</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <div class="panel-body fixed-panel">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                    @Html.DropDownList("List", new SelectList(ViewBag.List, "ListID", "ListDescription"), "Select", new { id = "List1"})
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <div class="panel-body fixed-panel">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                     @Html.DropDownList("List", new SelectList(ViewBag.List, "ListID", "ListDescription"), "Select", new { id = "List1"})
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

"

Jquery To check for validation and close the tab and open the next tab:-

```
    $('.nexttab').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
         var sectionValid = true;
         section = $(this).closest('.tab-pane.fade');
         $.each(section.find('input'), function () {
            if (!$(this).valid()) {
                sectionValid = false;
            }
        });

        if (sectionValid) {
            // collapse current section:
            section.collapse('toggle');
            // find and uncollapse next section:
            section.next().find('.tab-pane.fade').collapse('toggle');
        }
    });
```

I have go to close the active tab by "section.collapse('toggle');" however not able to open the next on on clicking the next tab. Any help will be highly appreciated. I am still trying my hands at asp mvc,so i could have missed the obvious.

Comment: are you using jquery-ui or bootstrap?

Comment: i am using Bootstrap. I am able to validate and close the current tab using "section.collapse('toggle');"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I cleaned up the tab markup a bit, wrapped it with a form (required by jquery validate) and used `.tab()` instead of `.collapse()`.

See http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs for the relevant documentation.

```js
$('.nexttab').click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  var sectionValid = true;
  section = $(this).closest('.tab-pane.fade');
  sectionValid = section.closest('form').valid();

  if (sectionValid) {
    // find and uncollapse next section:
    $(".nav-tabs .active a").closest("li").next().find("a").tab("show");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form>

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-left">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <div class="panel-body fixed-panel">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3">

          </div>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-default pull-right nexttab">Continue</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <div class="panel-body fixed-panel">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <div class="panel-body fixed-panel">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @jrummell for such quick turnaround. I am hoping that one day i will be able to contribute too by answering questions on ASP MVC. Cheers.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the .tab('show') instead of .collapse('toggle').